# Stream not writing on a file

Tags: c#, file

Is there anything wrong with this piece of code ? It's opening the file , yet it doesn't write on it.

```
fl = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
sw = new StreamWriter(fl);
sw.WriteLine("Hello ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to call [Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method?

```
sw.Flush();
```

Answer (score 4):

The proper way of doing this would be:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
    sw.WriteLine("Hello ");
```

This will call `sw.Flush()`, `sw.Close()` and `sw.Dispose()`.

Answer (score 2):

`StreamReader` uses a buffer. You can force the output by using `Flush()`, but in most cases you should just make sure you use `using()` which will call `Dispose` at the end and flush all remaining data.